# Access external drive over ssh on MacOS

Tags: macos, ssh, apple-m1, mounted-volumes

I have a new M1 iMac with a 4TB external (USB) drive attached. On the iMac I can access the contents of that drive, named "Data" at `/Volumes/Data`.

I use ssh to remotely access this iMac, and would like to be able to access the contents of `/Volumes/Data`. However, when I try I get "Operation not permitted".

I have gone into System Preferences, under Security & Privacy, and added Terminal, iTerm2, and bash (/opt/homebrew/bin/bash) to the list under Full Disk Access. This is mirrored automatically in Files and Folders. I've also added the same items to Developer Tools. All to no avail, I still get the "Operation not permitted" error when trying to do a `cd`  or `ls`  command against `/Volumes/Data`.

Some of my search results have suggested turning SIP off. I am reluctant to do this unless absolutely necessary.

I did try running `chflags -R nouchg .` in `/Volumes/Data` while on the iMac, but that also didn't resolve the issue.

Moving the external drive to a MacBook Pro (I.e., an Intel-based architecture) allows the contents of the external drive to be accessed remotely. The "Operation not permitted" error only happens when the external drive is attached to an M1-based Mac.

Is there a setting or preference that I've missed that will permit remote access to external hard drives on an M1-based Mac?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. You will probably have better luck at apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: That's fair. Additionally, I've stumbled onto the answer. `ssh-keygen-wrapper` under "Full Disk Access" in the Security & Privacy pane needs to be checked (enabled) to allow remote access to external drives.